# Get selected contenteditable's class, with dynamically generated contenteditables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I created a Sudoku grid with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
The user can type into any of the 81 dynamically generated cells (contenteditable divs).

Each cell has a class `"cell"` and a class `"cell" + number of the cell`. 
e.g. the first cell has class = `"class class1"`, the second `"class class2"`, ...

But I need a function that returns the index of the selected cell. 
e.g. here [image]
I want the function to return `0`

and here [image]
I want the function to return `80`

This is my HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "sudoku.css" type = "text/css">
        <script src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' type = "text/javascript"></script>
        <script src = "sudoku.js"></script>
        <title>Sudoku</title>
    </head>
    <body onload = "load(); draw()">
        <h1>Sudoku</h1>
        <div class = "board"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is part of the js file

```js
let bo = [];
for(let i = 0; i < num ** 2; i++) {
    bo.push("0")
}

// Redrawing Grid and Numbers
function draw() {
    $(".board").remove();
    let b = document.createElement("div");
    b.className = "board";
    document.body.appendChild(b)
    document.getElementsByClassName("board").innerHTML = "";
    // Drawing Cells
    for (let i = 1; i <= num ** 2; i++) {
        // Draw Cell
        let element = document.createElement("div");
        element.className = "cell cell" + i.toString();
        element.contentEditable = "true";
        element.setAttribute("onkeydown", "limit()")

        // Adding content
        let content;
        if (bo[i - 1] == "0") {
            content = document.createTextNode("");
        } else {
            content = document.createTextNode(bo[i - 1]);
        }
        element.appendChild(content);
        let div = document.getElementsByClassName("board")[0];
        div.append(element);
    }
}

// Update Cells
function save() {
    for (let i = 0; i < num ** 2; i++) {
        let c = document.getElementsByClassName("cell")[i];
        if (c.innerHTML == "") {
            bo[i] = "0";
        } else {
            bo[i] = c.innerHTML;
        }
    }
}


// Refreshing
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    switch (e.key) {
        case "1":
        case "2":
        case "3":
        case "4":
        case "5":
        case "6":
        case "7":
        case "8":
        case "9":
            save();
            break;
        case "Backspace":
            draw();
            break;
        case "ArrowLeft":
        case "ArrowRight":
            break;
        default:
            save();
            draw();
    }
})
```

Substantially I have a function that, if the key pressed is not a number, redraws the grid and readds all numbers. But pressing the backspace, it doesn't delete the number in the cell, so I want to know what is the selected cell to delete it using JavaScript.

1 week I'm on this problem and I can't find any solution online.

Comment: Incremental class values are not good practice. For something like this you should use the index of the cell within its parent. Also note that if you require a specific answer to your issue, please add the relevant HTML and JS code to the question, not images of its output.

Comment: I need a general solution, valid in any similar situation.

Comment: Ok, then using the index of the cells is your answer.

Comment: ok, but how exactly? I have just a selected contenteditable, I don't know his index. The index is the information I want.

Comment: As I said, if you need a specific answer we need to see your code. How you use indexes with this is entirely dependent on what the HTML structure looks like

Comment: ok, now I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it myself by checking, using a for loop, if a cell is selected, and then deleting the content of that cell.

Here's the code

```js
// Update Cells
function check() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= num ** 2; i++) {
        let cla = ".cell" + i.toString();
        if ($(cla).is(":focus")) {
            bo[i - 1] = "";
        }
    }
}
function save() {
    for (let i = 0; i < num ** 2; i++) {
        let c = document.getElementsByClassName("cell")[i];
        if (c.innerHTML == "") {
            bo[i] = "0";
        } else {
            bo[i] = c.innerHTML;
        }
    }
}

// Refreshing
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    switch (e.key) {
        case "1":
        case "2":
        case "3":
        case "4":
        case "5":
        case "6":
        case "7":
        case "8":
        case "9":
            save();
            break;
        case "Backspace":
            save();
            check();
            draw();
            break;
        case "ArrowLeft":
        case "ArrowRight":
            break;
        default:
            save();
            draw();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep things simple, don't worry about the `index` instead just give each div a data attribute of `i`.

```
element.setAttribute("data-index",i);
```

Then in your `onkeydown` handler you would use this to get that value

```
index = element.getAttribute("data-index");
```

You can reference a specific element using querySelector:

```
index = 1;
el = document.querySelector("[data-index='" + index + "']");
```

Comment: I think this leads to the same problem. How do I know the element which has the index I want? If I knew the index I would simply do it like `bo[i] = ""`

Comment: In the end, I was able to solve it myself. Thank you anyway.